# How does the sorting of a collection on an array field of MongoDB work?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a field in my MongoDB object. This is a DateTimeOffset so it gets saved as an array with the 0th value being the amount of ticks and the 1th value being the offset.
An example :
[0]=638279376932483480
[1]=0

The offset is always 0 because the dates are saved in UTC.

My database contains dates ranging from 2009 to 2023.
When sorting like this : { 'Field': 1 } it gives me a result of 2023 and the following up values do seem to be sorted by date but further down the list it seems to be wrong.
But when I use : { 'Field.0': 1 } it gives me the accurate result, an object from 2009.

I can't seem to figure out on what exactly it's sorting when using { 'Field': 1 }.
I wasn't able to find an answer in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official documentation about sorting based on array field.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#arrays

You are performing an `ascending` sort from lowest to highest value (`1` : ascending, `-1` : descending).

According to the doc `A less-than comparison, or an ascending sort, compares the smallest elements of the array according to the BSON type sort order.`

So it will compare the lowest BSON type of each array.

Imagine you try to compare these four arrays :

```
array1 = ["abc" (String), 638279376932483480 (Date), 0 (Number)]
array2 = [638279376932483480 (Date), 2 (Number)]
array3 = ["abc" (String), null (null), 638279376932483480 (Date)]
array4 = ["aaa" (String), false (Boolean)]
```

Internally, Mongo will reduce these array according to their type for the sort operation, following this [`priority order`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#comparison-sort-order) :

1. MinKey (internal type)
2. Null
3. Numbers (ints, longs, doubles, decimals)
4. Symbol, String
5. Object
6. Array
7. BinData
8. ObjectId
9. Boolean
10. Date
11. Timestamp
12. Regular Expression
13. MaxKey (internal type)

So your three arrays become :

```
array1 = 0 (priority 3)
array2 = 2 (priority 3)
array3 = null (priority 2)
array4 = "aaa" (priority 4)
```

Then you sort according the priority from lowest to highest.

So you get :

```
array3 (priority 2 is lower than 3)
array1 (priority 3, and lowest value for same priority)
array2 (priority 3, and highest value for same priority)
array4 (priority 4)
```

Hope that helped you understand.

I suggest you to try for yourself on [mongoplayground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/93BtzzgI-rE)

To conclude, in your specific case, every array is reduced to the number 0 (the offset you mentionned) which is the lowest element in your array. Then it compares 0 with 0 and return documents in an order that seems random.

Sorting on the first element of you array is the good solution for your case !